# How to clear a dictionary after return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am having issue cleaning dictionaries after return the one.
I am using fastAPI and my API GET an Age value then I create a list of ages with 4 values including my received value.

I am looking to receive always 4 values only the input age and the other ones, in first execution the code works correctly but if I change the age the dictionary increase in one and add the new age and I have 5 values in the array.

Example code:

```
my_final_return={}

@api_router.get("/example-stackoverflow", tags=['Simulations'])
def example(*,current_age:int):

    ages_list = [current_age,40,45,50]
    
    for i in ages_list:
        my_final_return[i]={
            "current_age":i*2
        }

    return my_final_return
```

The result in first execution is correct:

[image]

However if I add a different age the new one is added also (my problem):

[image]

Comment: The `my_final_return` is reused across requests. Move the definition of `my_final_return` into the body of `example` unless you have a reason for it to exist at the module scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your dictionary is instantiated outside of the function.

```
@api_router.get("/example-stackoverflow", tags=['Simulations'])
def example(*,current_age:int):
    my_final_return={}
    ages_list = [current_age,40,45,50]
    
    for i in ages_list:
        my_final_return[i]={
            "current_age":i*2
        }

    return my_final_return
```

this will clear it out when you call the function again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have an small question from your answer Is there a way to keep always 4 values? as you can see in my same example if I insert 40 as current_age I receive 3 values only.

Comment: That would be because 40 is already a key in your dictionary. Dictionary keys are unique. and if you try to insert a  new value with an existing key, it will overwrite it. One way around this could be to use a list of tuples ie ```[(i,{'current_age':i*2),(--,{--:--})]```